# Based on a condition, how to fill columns with column names whose row are not null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello my problem is almost the same as this post : [How to fill in a column with column names whose rows are not NULL in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71423043/how-to-fill-in-a-column-with-column-names-whose-rows-are-not-null-in-pandas)

But in my case, instead of doing a concatenation, I need to fill the column based on wether the columns name are a Country or a Segment.

**Edit : the table**
[image: An image of the data]
Originally I have this :

| Segment | Country | Segment 1 | Country 1 | Segment 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nan | Nan | 123456 | 123456 | Nan |
| Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| Nan | Nan | Nan | 123456 | 123456 |
| Nan | Nan | Nan | 123456 | 123456 |

Actually I have this (The first columns are filled by the two lines before the last in my code :

| Segment | Country | Segment 1 | Country 1 | Segment 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Seg1 ; Country1 ; | Seg1 ; Country1 ; | 123456 | 123456 | Nan |
| Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| country1 ; seg2 ; | country1 ; seg2 ; | Nan | 123456 | 123456 |
| country1 ; seg2 ; | country1 ; seg2 ; | Nan | 123456 | 123456 |

And I need this :

| Segment | Country | Segment 1 | Country 1 | Segment 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Segment 1 | Country1 | 123456 | 123456 | Nan |
| Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| Segment 2 | country1 | Nan | 123456 | 123456 |
| Segment 2 | country1 | Nan | 123456 | 123456 |

**Edit : My code Actually look like that after trying to integrate the anwser :**
Error is : `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?`

```
#For each column in df, check if there is a value and if yes : first copy the value into the 'Amount' Column, then copy the column name into the 'Segment' or 'Country' columns
for column in df.columns[3:]:
    valueList = df[column][3:].values
    valueList = valueList[~pd.isna(valueList)]
    def detect(d):
        cols = d.columns.values
        dd = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=d.index.unique())
        for col in cols:
            s = d[col].loc[d[col].str.contains(col[0:3], case=False)].str.replace(r'(\w+)(\d+)', col + r'\2')
            dd[col] = s
        return dd

    #Fill amount Column with other columns values if NaN
    if column in isSP:
        df['Amount'].fillna(df[column], inplace = True)
        df['Segment'] = df.iloc[:, 3:].notna().dot(df.columns[3:] + ';' ).str.strip(';')
        df['Country'] = df.iloc[:, 3:].notna().dot(df.columns[3:] + ' ; ' ).str.strip(';')
        df[['Segment', 'Country']] = detect(df[['Segment', 'Country']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split(r'\s+[+]\s+').explode()))
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you identify if a given string is a segment or a country?

Comment: To determine if the header is a Segment, I use this line :
isSP = [col for col in df.columns if "_sp" in col]

And for the country it's all the other, but ideally I'd like to use a list Countries.csv (The list is in the folder of the project).

Comment: Segments all have "_sp" in their name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
         Segment        Country  Segment 1  Country 1  Segment 2
0  Seg1;Country1  Seg1;Country1    123456    123456       Nan
1            Nan            Nan       Nan       Nan       Nan
2  country1;seg2  country1;seg2       Nan    123456    123456
3  country1;seg2  country1;seg2       Nan    123456    123456
```

Doing

```
cols = ['Segment', 'Country']
df[cols] = df.Segment.str.split(';', expand=True)

is_segment = 'eg' # ~You'll used '_sp' here~

# Let's sort values with a custom key, namely,
# does the string (not) contain what we're looking for?
key = lambda x: ~x.str.contains(is_segment, na=False)
func = lambda x: x.sort_values(key=key, ignore_index=True)
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(func, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Segment   Country Segment 1 Country 1 Segment 2
0    Seg1  Country1    123456    123456       Nan
1     Nan      None       Nan       Nan       Nan
2    seg2  country1       Nan    123456    123456
3    seg2  country1       Nan    123456    123456
```

---

Regex-heavy version:

```
pattern = '(?P<Segment>.+eg\d);(?P<Country>.+)|(?P<Country_>.+);(?P<Segment_>.+eg\d)'
extract = df.Segment.str.extract(pattern)
for col in cols:
    df[col] = extract.filter(like=col).bfill(axis=1)[col]
```